# PHP - IF two variables are equal, re-randomize one?

Tags: php, random

I'm fairly new to coding PHP from scratch and am trying to code a simple little app as a challenge. The idea is for it to take a couple of .txt files and pick a random fantasy football team from the names inside those files. I'm sure there's a shorter/easier way of doing what I've done so far, but what I've written works up to a point - except I can't seem to make it re-randomize a player when it pulls the same player twice. Where am I going wrong?

All code so far is below.

```
// Goalkeeper
$f_contents_goalkeepers = file("goalkeepers.txt"); // Load the Goalkeepers Database and add it to an array
shuffle($f_contents_goalkeepers); // Shuffle the contents of the array
$randGoalkeeper = $f_contents_goalkeepers[array_rand($f_contents_goalkeepers)]; // Add a random goalkeeper to the randGoalkeeper variable
$goalkeeper = $randGoalkeeper; // Set the Goalkeeper variable to use the random goalkeeper
//

// Defender
$f_contents_defenders = file("defenders.txt"); // Load the Defenders Database and add it to an array
shuffle($f_contents_defenders); // Shuffle the contents of the array
$randDefender1 = $f_contents_defenders[array_rand($f_contents_defenders)]; // Add a random defender to the randDefender1 variable
$randDefender2 = $f_contents_defenders[array_rand($f_contents_defenders)]; // Add a random defender to the randDefender2

    // If $randDefender2 is the same as $randDefender1, pick another player
    if($randDefender2 == $randDefender1) {
        $randDefender2 = $f_contents_defenders[array_rand($f_contents_defenders)];
    }

$randDefender3 = $f_contents_defenders[array_rand($f_contents_defenders)]; // Add a random defender to the randDefender variable

    // If $randDefender3 is the same as $randDefender2, pick another player
    if($randDefender3 == $randDefender2) {
        $randDefender3 = $f_contents_defenders[array_rand($f_contents_defenders)];
    }

$randDefender4 = $f_contents_defenders[array_rand($f_contents_defenders)]; // Add a random defender to the randDefender variable

    // If $randDefender4 is the same as $randDefender3, pick another player
    if($randDefender4 == $randDefender3) {
        $randDefender4 = $f_contents_defenders[array_rand($f_contents_defenders)];
    }

$defender1 = $randDefender1; // Set the Defender variable to use the random defender
$defender2 = $randDefender2;
$defender3 = $randDefender3;
$defender4 = $randDefender4;

echo "Goalkeeper: " . ' ' . $goalkeeper . ' ' . "<br />";

echo "Defender: " . ' ' . $defender1 . ' ' . "<br />";
echo "Defender: " . ' ' . $defender2 . ' ' . "<br />";
echo "Defender: " . ' ' . $defender3 . ' ' . "<br />";
echo "Defender: " . ' ' . $defender4 . ' ' . "<br />";
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're `shuffle()`ing the array, you can write your algorithm in a way where you don't have to worry about re-randomizing. Each time it's shuffled, it will be in a different order - so you can use the first and second items in the array, and they're guaranteed to be different. You could either use `$defenders[0]` and `$defenders[1]` to take them, or [`array_pop()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-pop.php) an element off the array. This approach is particularly useful if you're writing code that doesn't know in advance how many you'll need, as you don't have to maintain a count. Just load your defenders list, `shuffle()` it, and use `array_pop()` to get a different defender when necessary.

Answer (score 0):

You could solve your problem by letting the [array_rand](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-rand.php) pick all values for you.

`$defenders = array_rand(f_contents_defenders, 4);`

Now to answer your question, I must first fix an error. The `$f_contents_defenders[array_rand($f_contents_defenders)]` statement makes no sense. The result of `array_rand($f_contents_defenders)` is already a value, so, no need to index that.

Once you get that out of the way, you have:
    $randDefender1 = array_rand($f_contents_defenders); // Add a random defender to the randDefender1 variable
    $randDefender2 = array_rand($f_contents_defenders); // Add a random defender to the randDefender2

To make sure that you'll always get a different one the second time, you can do:

```
while ($randDefender1 == $randDefender2) {
    $randDefender2 = array_rand($f_contents_defenders); // Add a random defender to the randDefender2
}
```

And so forth. Make sure you have more than 2 defenders, or else you'll get stuck on a loop.

When going for the 3rd and 4th, you need to check with all previous defenders like so:

```
while ($randDefender3 == $randDefender1 || $randDefender3 == $randDefender2)
```

If not, you can get a situation like this:

- Defender C
- Defender A
- Defender C
- Defender A

I'd strongly consider you using the `array_rand()` to grab everything to you, tough.

Answer (score 0):

more beautiful way to do it:

```
// Goalkeeper
$f_contents_goalkeepers = file("goalkeepers.txt"); // Load the Goalkeepers Database and add it to an array
shuffle($f_contents_goalkeepers); // Shuffle the contents of the array
$randGoalkeeper = $f_contents_goalkeepers[array_rand($f_contents_goalkeepers)]; // Add a random goalkeeper to the randGoalkeeper variable
$goalkeeper = $randGoalkeeper; // Set the Goalkeeper variable to use the random goalkeeper
//

// Defender
$f_contents_defenders = file("defenders.txt"); // Load the Defenders Database and add it to an array
$def_cnt = count($f_contents_defenders)-1;
if($def_cnt < 3)
    die('You need 4 or more defenders');
$def_rand = array();
for($i = 0; $i < 4; ++$i)
{
    $rand_numb = rand(0, $def_cnt);
    while(isset($def_rand[$rand_numb]))
    {
        $rand_numb = rand(0, $def_cnt);
    }
    $def_rand[$rand_numb] = $f_contents_defenders[$rand_numb];
}
$def_rand = array_values($def_rand);
print_r($def_rand);
```